# Increment counter for single element JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I found one script for auto increment counter and it's for more elements.

I want to make it for one single element. It uses .each and I don't need that - how to remove each?

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shiva"><span class="counter">200</span></div>
```

Comment: What's the problem with `.each()`?

Comment: I dont want to use .each because it select more elements, and in near future i want to add other elements that i dont want to be coutners

Comment: So give that counter a different or an additional class

Comment: I dont want that guys, any chance you help me with .each only for a single element?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/z2xxxpyb/

Comment: @mplungjan thank you man, you are life saver